# adding key to all values in an already existing javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, key

I have this array:

```
myArray=['joe', 'sarah', 'jack', 'steph']
```

I want to add the key `name` to it so it becomes like this:

```
myArray=[{name: 'joe'}, {name: 'sarah'}, {name: 'jack'}, {name: 'steph'}]
```

I have tried:

```
myArray.map(o => ({ name: o, ...o }));
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the spread syntax which is spreading the characters of the string into the object.

```js
myArray=['joe', 'sarah', 'jack', 'steph']
console.log(myArray.map(o => ({ name: o})));
```